# Some functions don't show up when running a REPL via nailgun server

Tags: clojure, vimclojure

I am trying to use [appengine-magic (0.3.1)](https://github.com/gcv/appengine-magic) setup with VimClojure (2.2.0) and Clojure 1.2.0.

Things look right when used via vanilla REPL (`lein repl`).

```
user=> (require '[clojure.contrib.ns-utils :as nsu])
nil
user=> (require '[appengine-magic.core :as ae])
nil
user=> (nsu/ns-vars 'appengine-magic.core)
(appengine-environment-type def-appengine-app
 default-war-root in-appengine-interactive-mode? open-resource-stream
 start start* stop stop* wrap-war-static)
```

But when the same code is sent from VimClojure to nailgun server:

```
java -cp "`lein classpath`" vimclojure.nailgun.NGServer 127.0.0.1
```

Some functions and macros disappear.

```
user=> (require '[clojure.contrib.ns-utils :as nsu])
nil
user=> (require '[appengine-magic.core :as ae])
nil
user=> (nsu/ns-vars 'appengine-magic.core)
(appengine-environment-type def-appengine-app
 in-appengine-interactive-mode? open-resource-stream)
```

The same version of `appengine-magic` jar is definitely in the classpath.

So, is it a bug or misconfiguration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks more like a feature to me.

Check out the last form in https://github.com/gcv/appengine-magic/blob/master/src/appengine_magic/core.clj. The fns loaded up in that namespace are precisely dependent on whether you're running Swank or the normal REPL.

I can't speak to why that is, but it's clearly the intended behavior of appengine-magic.

Comment: Yep, I figured out that was the case, just was waiting for the upstream to pull my fix before posting self-answer. :)